# Accessing an ArrayAccess item directly

Tags: php

I'm trying to get an item of an array by its key. The array is in fact a SolrObject, which implements ArrayAccess, so I understand that I can access its items as I would in an array.

This is the structure of my $myobject:

```
SolrObject Object
(
    [116809] => SolrObject Object
    (
        [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => First value
        )

        [description] => Array
        (
            [0] => Second value
        )

    )

    [591978] => SolrObject Object
    (
        [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Third value
        )

        [description] => Array
        (
            [0] => Forth value
        )
    )
)
```

So, if I try

```
var_dump($myobject[116809]);
```

I get NULL.

But if I try

```
echo array_key_exists(116809, $myobject);
```

I get **1**

If I try to iterate $myobject with a foreach, I can access its elements correctly.

**Why can't I access directly one element by its key?**

**EDIT:**
Answering to @ircmaxell, this is the var_dump:

```
object(SolrObject)#219 (50) {
  [116809]=>
  object(SolrObject)#220 (2) {
    ["title"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(43) "First value"
    }
    ["description"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(82) "Second value"
    }
  }
  [591978]=>
  object(SolrObject)#221 (2) {
    ["title"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(104) "Third value"
    }
    ["description"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(95) "Fourth value"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the result of var_dump($myobject->getPropertyNames());

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: I know, but this object implements ArrayAccess. How could I achieve what I need?

Comment: It's the offsetGet method that is invoked when you do something like $solr['xyz']. Have you tried calling that method directly for testing purposes?

Comment: @Russell: Yes you can.  If the object implements `ArrayAccess`, it does allow you to access the object like an array.  @David: As far as this issue goes, try testing with `isset($myobject[116809])`.  Also, show a `var_dump($myobject)`.  I have a feeling the base object is not of `SolrObject`...  I could be wrong, but looking at the docs, it appears like it should be different...

Comment: Oops guess I learnt something new today.

Comment: @VolkerK: $myobject->offsetGet(116809) returns nothing.

Comment: Well, there's your problem.  The keys that are assigned are both empty (so theoretically, doing `$myobject[""]` should get one of them).  How are you creating these objects?

Comment: I'm using the php_solr extension in PHP 5.3.3, and this object is retrieved by the getResponse() method of the SolrQueryResponse class (http://www.php.net/manual/en/solrresponse.getresponse.php).

Comment: It seems like something's messed up in your Solr impelementation.  Perhaps you can try raising a bug report for it?  That would be my next move (or at least trying on a PHP Solr specific forum with their devs)...

Comment: Bug reported: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53183

Comment: According to the comment at http://www.php.net/manual/en/solrobject.getpropertynames.php, there could be an invisible character in a key, if you can loop through the properties with `foreach`, what does an `for($i = 0;$i<strlen($key);$i++) var_dump(ord($key[$i]));` give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it was a bug of the PHP Solr extension.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not implement the ArrayAccess methods correctly.